# RegEx for matching digits and failing on special chars

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

My regex below matches everything with this `千` character after the digits. I want to be able to match only if `千` is present but not if it is followed by `伏` or `吨`

```
\(\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?[ ]?)(!千伏|!千吨|千)\
```

Currently:

```
220千伏 (match '220千')
220千吨 (match '220千')
220千 (match '220千')
```

Expected:

```
220千伏 (no match)
220千吨 (no match)
220千 (match '220千')
```

Comment: You need to use a negative lookahead.

Comment: Why are you escaping `(` and `,`? And what is the backslash at the end for?

Comment: @Barmar The backslashes at the beginning/end are probably typo'd versions of `/` (regex delimiter).

Comment: FYI, quantifier `{1,}` is usually written as `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you may want to have a list to exclude certain things and have other specific chars, maybe something similar to:

```
\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*(?!千伏|千吨)(?:千)
```

#### RegEx

You can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6X44yF/1).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*(?!千伏|千吨)(?:千)/gm;
const str = `220千伏
220千吨
220千`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Also, you might not want to escape non-metachars, just like [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) advised, which you could modify this part of your expression:

```
\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason for '(\d{1,}(?:\,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?[ ]?)' is such that it also matches 220.2千, 2,020.2千, and 2,099 千

Answer (score 0):

See below for a working version of the regex.

The main idea is to use `千(?![伏吨])`, which is a literal `千` followed by a negative look-ahead assertion (and `[` `]` is just a character class, as usual). It matches a 千, but only if not followed by 伏 or 吨.

(I've also removed redundant parentheses, changed `{1,}` to `+`, and anchored the match to the beginning of the string. If you don't want that, consider at least using a `\b` (word boundary) anchor at the beginning.)

```js
const inputs = [
  '220千伏',
  '220千吨',
  '220千',
];

for (const str of inputs) {
  console.log(
    str + (
      /^\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?[ ]?千(?![伏吨])/.test(str)
        ? ' (match)'
        : ' (no match)'
    )
  );
}
```